# Is there a way of writing layout such that all the controllers refering to that layout will automatically display the block?

Tags: magento-1.8

Is there a way of writing layout such that all the controllers refering to that layout will automatically display the block's if no specific handle has been defined.

**what i actually want is** that, Is there any specific handle which acts as default handle such that any URl(handle) that is not specified in the layout will use that as their default..?

ex

```
<xyz_handle>
   <block type="core/template" name="default" template="def/default.phtml" />

</xyz_handle>
```

and if i call a handle in my url as aaa_index_index and that this hanle is  not defined in our layout file then by default it will use the `<xyz_handle>` handle .

Is there a way of doing this ?

Comment: Or do you want to define a fallback other than default? If the handle is not present in the layout.xml files, add this handle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add into the controller your own layout handle like that:

```
class Namespace_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('myhandle');
    }
}
```

The other solution is to use an event `controller_action_predispatch` and set the the handle in the same way as in the controller itself.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `<default>` this is processed first and on every request.